# How to fix the row size and columns size to fix tables

Tags: tables, fonts, columns, size

i want to fix the font size or cell size to do the table looks better. My code is as follow:

```
\begin{table}
    \centering
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ {\raggedright\arraybackslash}}
        % {>{\centering}p{0.17\textwidth}p{0.18\textwidth}p{0.18\textwidth}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.18\textwidth}p{0.18\textwidth}}
    \toprule
        \textbf{Posición} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Características}}\\ 
    \midrule
        \multicolumn{1}{p{60pt}}{\texttt{Defensas}} &
        \multicolumn{2}{p{60pt}}{\centering \% Duelos defensivos ganados} &  \multicolumn{1}{p{60pt}}{\centering \% Duelos aéreos ganados} & \multicolumn{3}{p{60pt}}{\centering \% Pases correctos} & \multicolumn{4}{p{60pt}}{\centering Faltas cada 90 minutos} \\
    \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{p{60pt}}{ \texttt{Mediocampistas}} &
        \multicolumn{2}{p{60pt}}{\centering \% Pases correctos} &  \multicolumn{1}{p{60pt}}{\centering Intercepciones cada 90 minutos} & \multicolumn{3}{p{60pt}}{\centering \% Duelos defensivos ganados} & \multicolumn{4}{p{60pt}}{\centering \% Duelos ofensivos ganados} \\
    \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{p{60pt}}{ \texttt{Delanteros}} &
        \multicolumn{2}{p{60pt}}{\centering \% Duelos ofensivos ganados} &  \multicolumn{1}{p{60pt}}{\centering \% Remates al arco} & \multicolumn{3}{p{60pt}}{\centering Asistencias cada 90 minutos} & \multicolumn{4}{p{60pt}}{\centering \% Centros correctos} \\
    \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Tabla variables distancia euclediana}
\label{caracteristicas dist euclediana}
\end{table}
```

I need to fix the align to the first column (to left), also i think that is anothe font (?) i don't know why. And i would like to close the side sides of the table.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, I guess, you wanted to obtain the following output (Table 1). In the MWE below, I also included an alternative version (Table 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|lCCCC|}
    \hline
        \textbf{Posición} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{Características}}\\ 
    \hline
        Defensas &
        \% Duelos defensivos ganados &  \% Duelos aéreos ganados &  \% Pases correctos &  Faltas cada 90 minutos \\
    \hline
        Mediocampistas &
         \% Pases correctos &   Intercepciones cada 90 minutos &  \% Duelos defensivos ganados & \% Duelos ofensivos ganados \\
    \hline
        Delanteros &
        \% Duelos ofensivos ganados &  \% Remates al arco & Asistencias cada 90 minutos & \% Centros correctos \\
    \hline
        \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Tabla variables distancia euclediana}
\label{caracteristicas dist euclediana}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
    \caption{Tabla variables distancia euclediana}
    \label{caracteristicas dist euclediana}
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}l*{4}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}@{}}
    \toprule
        \textbf{Posición} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Características}}\\ 
    \cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(l){2-5}
        Defensas &
        \% Duelos defensivos ganados &  \% Duelos aéreos ganados &  \% Pases correctos &  Faltas cada 90 minutos \\
    \addlinespace
        Mediocampistas &
         \% Pases correctos &   Intercepciones cada 90 minutos &  \% Duelos defensivos ganados & \% Duelos ofensivos ganados \\
    \addlinespace
        Delanteros &
        \% Duelos ofensivos ganados &  \% Remates al arco & Asistencias cada 90 minutos & \% Centros correctos \\
    \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this will help -- please revert in case of difficulty

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
   
\begin{document}
   

\begin{table}
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{lllllllllll}
        % {>{\centering}p{0.17\textwidth}p{0.18\textwidth}p{0.18\textwidth}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.18\textwidth}p{0.18\textwidth}}
    \toprule
        \textbf{Posición} & \multicolumn{10}{c}{\textbf{Características}}\\ \cmidrule(lr){1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-11}
        \multicolumn{1}{p{60pt}}{{Defensas}} 
            &\multicolumn{2}{p{60pt}}{\raggedright \% Duelos defensivos ganados} 
                &  \multicolumn{1}{p{60pt}}{\raggedright \% Duelos aéreos ganados} 
                    & \multicolumn{3}{p{60pt}}{\raggedright \% Pases correctos} 
                        & \multicolumn{4}{p{60pt}}{\raggedright Faltas cada 90 minutos} \\ \midrule
        \multicolumn{1}{p{60pt}}{{Mediocampistas}} 
            &\multicolumn{2}{p{60pt}}{\raggedright \% Pases correctos} 
                &  \multicolumn{1}{p{60pt}}{\raggedright Intercepciones cada 90 minutos} 
                    & \multicolumn{3}{p{60pt}}{\raggedright \% Duelos defensivos ganados} 
                        & \multicolumn{4}{p{60pt}}{\raggedright \% Duelos ofensivos ganados} \\ \midrule
        \multicolumn{1}{p{60pt}}{{Delanteros}} 
            &\multicolumn{2}{p{60pt}}{\raggedright \% Duelos ofensivos ganados} 
                &  \multicolumn{1}{p{60pt}}{\raggedright \% Remates al arco} 
                    & \multicolumn{3}{p{60pt}}{\raggedright Asistencias cada 90 minutos} 
                        & \multicolumn{4}{p{60pt}}{\raggedright \% Centros correctos} \\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \caption{Tabla variables distancia euclediana}
\label{caracteristicas dist euclediana}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```